# Add constraint to already existing column to store Record Created Timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Existing column called CREATED DATE whose data type is "Date". I am trying to add a constraint to this CREATED DATE Column which will store "Record created time stamp". I have a following query in place but its working out. Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
   ALTER TABLE CONTAINER_SCAN_LOG  
MODIFY (CREATED_DATE DEFAULT (sysdate());
```

Comment: What is `GETDATE()`?  try `DEFAULT SYSDATE` instead.

Comment: @SYSDATE is showing only date. I want time also?

Comment: No, SYSDATE includes the current time.  However you may not be shown that (by default) when you view the data due to the default format mask in effect.

Comment: So what can I do to show the exact timestamp? I wanna show time in hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: `select to_char(created_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from container_scan_log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the error exactly ? what is the default date? anyway try to remove the parenthesis

```
   ALTER TABLE ex_employee  
MODIFY START_TIME DEFAULT (sysdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `timestamp` instead of date

```
alter table t add (created_datetime  timestamp default systimestamp)
```

or modify existing created_date to be of `timestamp` datatype and `systimestamp` default